# Initializer does not override a designated initializer Swift WatchKit

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I just updated the new beta of Xcode to continue work on my WatchKit app

I immediately got an error after updating for all of my WatchKit extension files

"Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass"

I wasn't receiving this error before I updated, not sure how to fix it.

Any insights?

Here is my code

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

override init(context: AnyObject?) {
    // Initialize variables here.
    super.init(context: context)

    // Configure interface objects here.
    NSLog("%@ init", self)
}

override func willActivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    super.willActivate()
    NSLog("%@ will activate", self)
}

override func didDeactivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
    NSLog("%@ did deactivate", self)
    super.didDeactivate()
}

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Beta 3 release initWithContext is now deprecated method. You should use `awakeWithContext`. `init` method of WKInterfaceController class is now designated initialiser.

Reference: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-8.2/index.html, section *Notes*.

Comment: You can create a new project and add iwatch target to it, to see how the template given has changed.

Answer (score 2):

You can call super on designated initializers only, and for [WKInterfaceController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/init) init() is the only one. You could take a closer look at awakeWithContext(_:) method.